# Using a variable after "for" loop

Tags: java, loops

I wrote a simple for loop which adds numbers from 1 to 10. Here is my code :

```
for(int x = 0 ; x <10 ; x++) {
    int sum =+ x; 
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

But when I try to use "sum" variable outside the loop, I get a error "sum cannot be resolved to a variable". Why? I just defined sum inside a loop and it has a variable! I am really confused.

Comment: You should read up on scoping - the `sum` variable only exists inside the for loop.

Comment: You answered your question in your post by yourself...

Comment: In Java, always think about where your variables are in the levels of the curly braces... it's a hierarchy. If you declare a variable inside a set of braces, you can't see that variable outside that scope

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. you were declaring `sum` inside of loop.
2. You were using `=+` instead of `+=`.

.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int x = 0 ; x <10 ; x++) {
    sum += x; 
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: What is the difference between =+ and += ? They both look correct.

Comment: `+=` is itself an assignment operator. `a += b` will be converted to `a = a + b` by compiler *particularly `a = (type of a)(a + b)` as stated by jls*. But `a =+ b` is equivalent to `a = (+b)` or `a = b`.

Comment: Thank you. Now I am trying to find average of them. I used "long" but result was like 15.0. I want to get results like 15.2 or 20.45. How can I make this?

Comment: You don't need to use `long`. `float average = (float) sum / 10;`

Answer (score 2):

You have declared it inside the `for` loop. so its scope is within the block and cant be accessible outside of the block

You can declare it outside the loop as ,

```
int sum=0;
for(int x = 0 ; x <10 ; x++)
        {
           sum += x;     
        }    
System.out.println(sum);
```

to print its value as desired . Read [Variable Scopes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141133/what-is-meant-by-scope-of-a-variable) and also [scope and lifetime of variables](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
   int sum  = 0 ;
   for(int x = 0 ; x <10 ; x++){
          sum += x;               
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit only 2 characters, so I'll comment: I guess you wanted to type `+=` instead of `=+`

Comment: @stuXnet i'm Edited question

Answer (score 1):

Your `sum` variable has been defined inside the scope of the for loop.

so the error

```
sum cannot be resolved to a variable
```

You should also define it outside of the loop as below:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; x++) 
{
    sum += x; 
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable outside the for loop or else it will be local to the loop's body

Answer (score 0):

Sum is improperly scoped.  you want this:

```
int sum = 0;
for(...)
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is everything you iterate through the loop , your computer creates a new `int` each and every time.

Try doing:

```
int sum=0;
for(int x = 0 ; x <10 ; x++){
    sum += x; 
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum` variable is scoped inside the loop. Hence, it can't be accessed outside of it.

You can declare it outside the loop however.

[Demo](http://ideone.com/CDay5W)

```
int sum =0; 
for(int x = 0 ; x <10 ; x++)
  {
    sum += x; 
  }
System.out.println(sum);
```

Also, it's supposed to be `+=` not `=+`

`+=` performs the summation on the `sum` variable. It tops up the variable `sum` each time in the loop's continuum. Meanwhile, `=+` updates the `x` variable. The value of `x` is updated each time the loop progresses, discarding previous values.

Hence, since this loop happens `9` times, you finally get the value of the last `x`, which is `9`, inserted into the `sum` variable. Therefore, in your older incorrect code, you were getting `sum=9`. In other words, `sum +=x` is the same as `sum = sum + x`

Comment: I did it like this but now result is 9. What's the problem here ?

Comment: @Dosher: I have explained this in more detail. Check answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that occurred in your code was due to scope of the variable.
Scope refers to the lifetime and accessibility of a variable.

How large the scope is depends on where a variable is declared. For example, if a variable is declared at the top of a class then it will accessible to all of the class methods. If it’s declared in a method then it can only be used in that method.

The correct version is as below :

```
   int sum = 0;
   for(int x = 0 ; x <10 ; x++)
    {
        sum += x; 
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `sum` that you have defined inside your `for` loop has a local scope. That means it can be used only inside the `for` loop. To use it outside you would have to declare outside the block as below.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int x = 0 ; x <10 ; x++) 
{
    sum += x; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the sum variable outside of the for loop. Also you should use += instead of =+

It will be like this

```
int sum = 0;
for(int x = 0 ; x < 10 ; x++) {
    sum += x; 
}
System.out.println(sum);
```